# Vapor(4.77) Leaf(4.2.4) 101: Unable to render a child leaf within its parent leaf (template)

Tags: vapor, leaf

**Environment:** 
Vapor v4.77 
Leaf v4.2.4

**Neophyte Goal:** To incorporate a child leaf into its parent leaf (template).

**Scenario:** Rendering the basic "hello" world is fine.  It works as a stand-alone.
However, I want to use the power of templates along with the dynamic of leaf tags, etc.

**Problem:** The problem centers around the #embed() & #include() tags.   It doesn't render the child.leaf.   The output is merely the 'embed' or 'include' word.

The URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/leaves/example?content-type=application/json
```

The target code:

```
func getExample(req: Request) async throws -> View {
        return try await req.view.render("parent", ["title": "Example"])
 }
```

parent.leaf:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>#(title)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Parent Leaf</h1>
    <h3>#(title)</h3>
    I'm trying to embed some shit here.
    #embed("child")
  </body>
</html>
```

Revised Parent Leaf, replacing #embed with #import:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>#(title)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Parent Leaf</h1>
    <h3>#(title)</h3>
    I'm trying to import some shit here.
    #import("child")
  </body>
</html>
```

child.leaf:

```
#extend("parent"):
#export("body"):
What are you looking at?
#endexport
#endextend
```

I tried with and without the #extend & #export tags. 
It makes no difference.

The generated HTML code via Postman™ reveals:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Parent Leaf</h1>
    <h3>Example</h3>
    I'm trying to import some shit here.

</body>

</html>
```

Both the parent & child leafs share the same View directory within Vapor.

[image]

Why doesn't the #embed (or #include) work?

---

Out of curiosity, I changed the target from parent to child:

```
#extend("parent"):
What are you looking at?
#endextend
```

This is what I got via Postman™:

```
<html>
I'm trying to embed some shit here.
</html>
```

Which matches the revised parent (without the #import):

```
<html>
    I'm trying to embed some shit here.
   #import("child.leaf")
</html>
```

... so apparently the #extend() works but both the #import and #embed don't.

---

I've tested the '#import("body")' per request and also asked my ChatDBT Bot to follow thru:

```
1) [Vapor v4.77] [Leaf 4.2.4]
func getExample(req: Request) async throws -> View {
        return try await req.view.render("parent", ["title": "Example"])
    }
2) parent.leaf:
<html>
    I'm trying to embed some shit here.
   #import("body")
</html>

3) child.leaf:
#extend("parent"):
What are you looking at?
#endextend


3) What is the expected Result?

<html>

  I'm trying to embed some shit here.
  
  What are you looking at?
  
</html>

5) However, this is the REAL result via Postman:

<html>

I'm trying to embed some shit here.


</html>
```

So my Claude AI Bot expected my child.leaf to be included with the parent (#3).   
However in REALITY, the child was ignored.

**Note:** I made sure the Child.leaf is available.

Answer (score 1):

In `parent.leaf` You need to replace your:

```
#embed("child")
```

with:

```
#import("body")
```

Oh dear, I missed the obvious! You also need to change your route to:

```swift
func getExample(req: Request) async throws -> View {
        return try await req.view.render("child", ["title": "Example"])
 }
```

If you think about it, it is obvious. Trying to render the 'parent' won't allow you to modify the template in any way, which is what you are seeing. You can have as many 'children' as you like and rendering these will allow you to use the template as such.

Comment: I tried this and got nothing.  Using 'import' yield blank.
Leaf obviously isn't ready for prime time.   I'm wasting my time with this.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, I have been using Leaf in production systems for years without any concerns about its credibility.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, does changing the render file solve it?

Comment: I've tried various combinations without success.  The #embed & #include don't function.   At the very least, they should behave intuitively.

Comment: Can you post the raw html outpu) from the #import and rendered child.leaf combo?

Comment: I've added the URL.   I've replaced #embed with #include and produce the raw output via Postman™.  Notice neither the #include statement nor the child appeared.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, Have you tried #import with parameter “body” as per my answer?

Comment: I've added 'body' to the child reference within the parent per your request.   I even ran thru the scenario via my AI Bot; which said that it should work (see revised writeup, above).  But again, the child is ignored.  I don't want to rewrite everything to see if any gremlins were created.

Comment: Can you add the relevant lines from configure.swift where you enable Leaf? It’s the only thing left but I am clutching at straws.

Comment: I ran the code thru my Chat AI Bot and it says the output would be as you suggest; but unfortunately not reality.

I did some research and found '.stencil' versus '.leaf' as a possible replacement.  .stencil is an Apple product that is similar to .leaf.   So I'll explore that.   I'll update this log if I discover something, particularly  a remedy.